# SDWebImage on iOS 5.1.1 - Parse Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an older project that still supports iOS 5.1.1, and SDWebImage is also supposed to have support for this. However, when I run the project, I'm getting many errors like this:

```
Apple LLVM compiler 4.2 Error
Expected ';' after method prototype
```

It's happening on lines like this:

```
- (void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url __deprecated_msg("Method deprecated. Use `sd_setImageWithURL:`");
```

Anything I can do to get this project to run? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using cocoapods, and if so, what is your OS requirement target set to?

Comment: Ahh youre a genius! If you put this as the answer, Ill accept it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using CocoaPods, make sure in your podfile you're using the correct target iOS version.

From your project folder, edit the podfile with your favorite text editor (I like nano)

```
nano podfile
```

Or you might like vi

```
vi podfile
```

Ensure the line at the top that declares the target iOS version is set correctly:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
```

Or in your case, probably

```
platform :ios, '5.1.1'
```

Comment: Actually I was wrong. The error is still there. I'm using Cocoapods but not for SDWebImage

Comment: Hrm, what if you try using it for SDWebImage?

Comment: Removing the library and re-adding it fixed the issue. I have other errors now but that's for a different question. Thanks!